# Error in DataSource for Telerik MVC DropDownTree

Tags: telerik, kendo-asp.net-mvc, telerik-mvc

My Telerik MVC Dropdowntree reports the error "Object doesn't support property or method 'level'" for the datasource.

Can someone take a look below and tell me what's wrong?

The MVC looks like this

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownTree()
                    .Name("dropdowntree")
                    .DataTextField("Name")
                    .DataValueField("Id")

                    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 100%" })
                    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                        .Read(read => read
                            .Action("DoLayers2", "Dev")
                        )
                    )
)
```

My controller returns the following JSON:

```
[  
   {  
      "Id":1,
      "ParentCategoryId":0,
      "Name":"First Layer",
      "items":[  
         {  
            "Id":2,
            "ParentCategoryId":1,
            "Name":"First SubLayer1",
            "items":[  

            ]
         },
         {  
            "Id":3,
            "ParentCategoryId":1,
            "Name":"First SubLayer2",
            "items":[  

            ]
         },
         {  
            "Id":4,
            "ParentCategoryId":1,
            "Name":"First SubLayer3",
            "items":[  

            ]
         }
      ]
   },
   {  
      "Id":5,
      "ParentCategoryId":0,
      "Name":"Second Layer",
      "items":[  
         {  
            "Id":6,
            "ParentCategoryId":5,
            "Name":"Second SubLayer1",
            "items":[  

            ]
         },
         {  
            "Id":7,
            "ParentCategoryId":5,
            "Name":"Second SubLayer2",
            "items":[  
               {  
                  "Id":8,
                  "ParentCategoryId":7,
                  "Name":"Sub -3",
                  "items":[  

                  ]
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Apparently my post has too much code and not enough details so I have to write something foolish at the end of the post to trick the system into allowing me to post it. This is rather annoying.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can return the whole tree and bind it to the dropdowntree...

If you check [telerik's demo](https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/dropdowntree/remote-data-binding) you see that they only returns one level at a time, so In your case I think it only wants first level Id:1 and Id:5 at first and then it will automatically ask for second level for each branch...
(Id:1 will return 2, 3, 4 and Id:5 will return 6, 7 and Id:7 will return 8)

You will also have to return if there are any children for each node:

```
[  
   { "Id":1, "Name":"First Layer", "hasChildren": true }, 
   { "Id":5, "Name":"Second Layer", "hasChildren": true }
]
```

Hope it helps!